# 0402 versus 0201 resistor footprints

Tags: resistors

I am writing a manufacturing specification for our contract manufacturing.

So far, the smallest component on our PCB is a 0402 resistor, however, I would like to specify a process that will be capable of handling our future requirements.

A design requirement we have is the reduction of the PCB layout size.  As such it might be better to go to 0201 resistors in the revision.

Does anyone know the differences between 0402 and 0201 footprint resistors?  Is it purely power and price or are there other things worth considering?

**edit**: interesting frequency response relation documented here: http://www.vishay.com/docs/60107/freqresp.pdf
"reduction in parasitic impedance for smaller cases sizes"

Comment: Top of head: Spark voltage and creep distance at the least.

Comment: Why only resistors, why not capacitors too. Also look at [choosing surface mount resistor/capacitors]( http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12409/choosing-surface-mount-resistor-capacitors)

Comment: Manufacturing failure rate might be of importance

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena hmm good link but no reference to 0201 "You do have to do some due diligence before choosing parts, namely:

are the parts rated for the expected power dissipation?
are the parts rated for the expected voltage?
is the design manufacturable?
Some generalizations:
1206 resistors: 0.25W maximum dissipation, 200V maximum
0805 resistors: 0.125W maximum dissipation, 150V maximum
0603 resistors: 100mW maximum dissipation, 75V maximum
0402 resistors: 62.5mW maximum dissipation, 50V maximum

Comment: Availability including stocked quantities of higher values and special types (high precision, pulse rated, sulphur resistant, non-magnetic) may be more limited as you go down in size.

Comment: Assembly costs will also likely go up. Careful PCB design to avoid tombstoning during reflow. Impossible to hand solder, so prototyping costs go up (prototypes would have to be machine assembled).

Comment: @TomCarpenter I've seen technicians manually place paste on a board using a microscope for BGA's and then place a BGA without a BGA machine.  Given I can place place 0402, I'd imagine a good reworker god do 0201 but maybe not?  Good point on tombstoning.

Comment: 0402 is relatively easy by hand (once you are getting good ;) ), but 0201 is so small you probably can't hold the part unless you have some very tiny tweezers. Breathe on one and it will probably be gone forever! Maybe impossible is a bit strong of a word, but incredibly difficult.

Comment: Pshh you can hand solder 201s easily any skilled tech should be able to do it as well

Comment: also if your cm can't handle 201s you're at the wrong cm :)

Comment: And you are right parasitics will go down and in the decoupling cap case the mounting inductance will be smaller as the loop area is reduced which should make them more effective assuming your out it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

0201 pros - smaller foot print and as a result smaller PCB.

0201 cons - not all P&P machines can do these tiny parts so you will have to find an assembly service provider that can handle such small parts and has the right machines for the job. He would probebly charge you extra too.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention, even in cell phones not always 0201 is used. It's still something you should avoid if you can.